How to create a Virtual layer with point geometry and count repetitions from 3 different tables
From 3 tables with the following fields:
PARENT_TABLE



CODE1
CODE2
XCOORD
XCOORD




12395
8604813EG7180S0001GX
418477,91
4620364,53


13505
8604813EG7180S0001GX
418477,91
4620364,53


12968
8604813EG7180S0001GX
418477,91
4620364,53


12758
8604813EG7180S0001GX
418505,91
4620339,07


13208
8605549EG7180N0004QJ
418513,25
4620328,71


13210
8605549EG7180N0004QJ
418523,92
4620312,81


12284
8603404EG7180S0014LO
418473,32
4620369,35


18436
8703306EG7180S0009MU
418593,37
4620192,22


16674
8605547EG7180N0006IL
418603,38
4620193,32


16678
8605547EG7180N0006IL
418491,55
4620344,03


16679
8605547EG7180N0006IL
418583,67
4620205,61


16680
8605547EG7180N0006IL
418572,92
4620238,87


16684
8605547EG7180N0006IL
418572,92
4620238,87


16693
8605570EG7180N0001FF
418572,92
4620238,87


19620
8605570EG7180N0001FF
418572,92
4620238,87


18473
8605570EG7180N0001FF
418572,92
4620238,87


18489
8605550EG7180N0001EF
418572,92
4620238,87


16722
8604822EG7180S0001MX
418672,92
4621238,87



CHILD_TABLE1



CODE1




12395


12395


12395


12395


13505


13505


13505


12968


12758


13208


13210


12284


12284


12284


18436


18436


18436


18436



CHILD_TABLE2



CODE1




16678


16678


16678


16678


16678


16680


16680


16680


16680


16680


16680


16680


16680


16680


16680


16680


16680


16680



I would like to obtain a virtual layer with point geometry that does the following:
1- Draw a points layer at the coordinates 'XCOORD' and 'YCOORD' of the PARENT_TABLE
2- Create the field 'REPETITION_PARENT' with the number of times the field 'CODE2' from PARENT_TABLE is repeated
3- Create the field 'REPETITION_CHILD1' with the number of times the field 'CODE1' from CHILD_TABLE1 is repeated
4- Create the field 'REPETITION_CHILD2' with the number of times the field 'CODE1' from CHILD_TABLE2 is repeated
For example, for the resulting layer with point geometry, the table structure would be:



CODE1
CODE2
XCOORD
XCOORD
REPETITION_FATHER
REPETITION_CHILD1
REPETITION_CHILD2




12395
8604813EG7180S0001GX
418477,91
4620364,53
4
4
0


13505
8604813EG7180S0001GX
418477,91
4620364,53
4
3
0


12968
8604813EG7180S0001GX
418477,91
4620364,53
4
1
0


12758
8604813EG7180S0001GX
418505,91
4620339,07
4
1
0


13208
8605549EG7180N0004QJ
418513,25
4620328,71
2
1
0


13210
8605549EG7180N0004QJ
418523,92
4620312,81
2
1
0


12284
8603404EG7180S0014LO
418473,32
4620369,35
1
3
0


18436
8703306EG7180S0009MU
418593,37
4620192,22
1
4
0


16674
8605547EG7180N0006IL
418603,38
4620193,32
5
0
0


16678
8605547EG7180N0006IL
418491,55
4620344,03
5
0
5


16679
8605547EG7180N0006IL
418583,67
4620205,61
5
0
0


16680
8605547EG7180N0006IL
418572,92
4620238,87
5
0
13


16684
8605547EG7180N0006IL
418572,92
4620238,87
5
0
0


16693
8605570EG7180N0001FF
418572,92
4620238,87
3
0
0


19620
8605570EG7180N0001FF
418572,92
4620238,87
3
0
0


18473
8605570EG7180N0001FF
418572,92
4620238,87
3
0
0


18489
8605550EG7180N0001EF
418572,92
4620238,87
1
0
0


16722
8604822EG7180S0001MX
418672,92
4621238,87
1
0
0



Solution I tried:
SELECT 
  t1.CODE1, 
  t2.CODE2, 
  COUNT(*) AS REPETITIONS,
  MakePoint(XCOORD,YCOORD,25831) as geometry
FROM PARENT_TABLE t1
JOIN CHILD_TABLE1 t2 ON t1.CODE1 = t2.CODE1
GROUP BY t1.CODE1, t2.CODE2
ORDER BY REPETITIONS DESC


CODE2 in the PARENT_TABLE is distributed over multiple records with different values for CODE1, so a simple GROUP BY will not work (although it might work with a separate subquery). Instead, the following example uses a window function in a subquery on PARENT_TABLE to collect the number of instances for CODE2, regardless of the values of CODE1 they appear with.
The result is then left-joined with both child tables to collect their respective counts.
As follows:
SELECT parent.*
, count(child_table1.code1) AS repetition_child1
, count(child_table2.code1) AS repetition_child2
FROM (
  SELECT code1
  , MakePoint(XCOORD,YCOORD,25831) as geometry
  , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY code2) AS repetition_father
  FROM parent_table
) AS parent
LEFT JOIN child_table1 ON parent.code1 = child_table1.code1
LEFT JOIN child_table2 ON parent.code1 = child_table2.code1
GROUP BY parent.code1, geometry, parent.repetition_father

